# Get from database set type field - Agile Toolkit

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks, agile, atk4

I've created a model which adds fields from database:

```
$this->addField('field')->type();
```

And the field type, I need to retrieve from database is 'set', but as far as I know, there is no type('set').
So, what can I do, to get that type?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $this->addField('colour')
         ->datatype('list')
         ->listData(array('r'=>'red','g'=>'green','y'=>'yellow'));
```